# How to disable or remove plugins from WebStorm IDE

Tags: plugins, webstorm

I have added DB plugins into Webstorm now Can anyone gives suggestion to remove the plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no way to remove, disable or uninstall from the IDE. So we need to delete the plugin files from the disk.
First, we need to locate the directory where all plugins exist. It depends on what OS you are using.

In the case of macOS it's
~/Library/Application Support/

You can refer to the following doc to locate plugin directory.
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519

I had to remove the **Material Theme** plugin from WebSorm So I did the following

First killed all instances of IDE then

```
cd ~/Library/Application Support/WebStorm2019.2
rm -rf Material Theme
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution :
Goto File -> settings -> plugins
   where you can do disable and enable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to uninstall:

> Go to plugins

> Select your plugin

> There are 3 dots near it: click on it

> You will have 2 choices uninstall or disable. select uninstall

> [this is an example of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg72T.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Plugin Explorer > Find your installed Plugin > Dropdown Right next to it > Uninstall > Restart IDE

[see example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFQ7u.png)